# VSCoq ProofView not printing

Tags: visual-studio-code, coq, vscode-extensions, coq-tactic, coqide

When using Visual Studio Code with enabled VSCoq and coq extensions, stepping through the proof works well but the ProofView window shows blank (no content).
What could be the issue and solutions to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, and i'm not familiar with VSCode. But sometimes my Emacs+Proof General does similar thing to what you've described. If this is the same issue, you can try just remove the last symbol in your proof script and you will see the proof goal and context in appropriate window.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Modifying the script does not help...